# COM Automation WScript.Shell Echo command not working

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, com, comautomationfactory

Hi I am trying to run an echo command using AutomationFactory but I get this error:

"The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)"

This is the code that I'm using:

```
dynamic shell = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Automation.AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.Run("echo xyz");
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
shell.Run("echo xyz >> C:\xyz.txt")
```

I also tried `shell.Echo("xyz");` But I get MissingMemberException.

Comment: The answer is below, but I really do need to ask why you're going through such trouble to do: System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\xyz.txt", "xyz");

Comment: I don't think silverlight allows you to do that. It will give you a security exception. You cannot directly access the file system. Even if you are running an Out-of-Browser, elevated trust application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` is a shell built-in, not a command, in the same way that `dir` or `rmdir` are. You need to execute them through the command interpreter:

```
shell.Run("cmd /c echo xyz >> C:\xyz.txt")
```